# How to ignore some models to migrate?

Tags: python, flask, alembic, flask-migrate

i have question.
I have models called `Visitor`, that i don't want to Migrate when i run `flask db migrate`, because i already have the table in database.
my question is how to avoid that models to become a table ?
here my `visitor.py`

```
class Visitor(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    Name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    DateDeparture = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    DateArrival = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    FlightNo = db.Column(db.String(15))
    LocationFrom = db.Column(
        db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('Location.id')
        )
    LocationTo = db.Column(
        db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('Location.id')
        )
    DriverId = db.Column(
        db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('Driver.id')
        )
    NoVehicle = db.Column(
        db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('Vehicle.id')
        )
    Marks = db.Column(db.Text())
    Status = db.Column(db.String(11))
    CancelMark = db.Column(db.Text())
    is_pickup = db.Column(db.String(1))
```

Thank you :)

Comment: You question sounds to me like: I want `Visitor` to be migrated, but not migrated. Can you clarify?

Comment: @KlausD. i don't want to migrate because i already have the table in database, but i need this models for querying data :)

Comment: @KlausD. oh my bad, my question is confusing, i just realize it ._.

Comment: @KlausD. oh right, it's seems like what i want. but i don't get clearly documentation for `__table_args__` in `sqlalchemy` documentation. but Thank you :)